# Is there a list of values that Alexa recognizes as a certain slot type?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I would like to make a simple game where Alexa picks 7 animal names at random and says them to a user. The user has to repeat the names in the reverse order.

I could use the AMAZON.Animal built-in slot type to listen for the animal names the user is saying. 
But is there any way I can use this list to have Alexa randomly pick the animal names that the user has to repeat?

The [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#list-slot-types) offers some sample values for every slot type.

Is there a more complete list for the AMAZON.Animal slot type?

I understand that the list can never be exhaustive as Amazon's must surely continuously expand it. I would just like to have a list of animal names that I can be sure of Alexa will understand.

Comment: It will help us respond better if you describe your use case more specifically.

Comment: @aberger I added more info to my question. Hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, you can't see the full list of slot values for Amazon built-ins. Instead, I recommend creating your own animal slot type. This way you will be able to randomly choose from that set of animal names. It will function exactly like the built in and you can modify it as you see fit.